# unable to access the attribute of source or origin component

Tags: angular

I have gone through documentation, source codes and tutorials but still can't understand what I am doing wrong.

All I need to do is:

```
<app myTitle='my awesome title'>
```

I want to access myTitle from the constructor.

Punker Code : `http://next.plnkr.co/edit/5731Z9N6tQ391gQtfZrA?preview`

Comment: Why are you using a really old version of Angular? Your Plunker is using a really old version of Angular v2, which IIRC has been deprecated and/or no longer supported.

Comment: @Sreeram: Try  https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the app.component.ts:

```
@input() public myTitle:string
```

1. yes. it's public by default.
2. yes, you need to import input from @angular/core

Comment: It's because he's using a really old version of Angular (v2.0.0-alpha.22), not because he didn't define an input correctly.

Comment: there was input annotation in ng V2 [docs](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html)